# Multiple checkbox, answers

Tags: laravel, checkbox

Hi I have a problem I have my question for example saved with two answers correct, but when i take the test and i click just one correct, it takes as correct. I want to do it when I don't click both answers as correct to show wrong answer, only when I click both to show correct.

```
  foreach($answers as $answer){
            $correct_answer = Answer::where('id', $answer)->where('correct', 1)->where('deleted',0)->get();

            if(count($correct_answer) == 1){
                $answer_result = 1;
            }else{
                $answer_result = 0;
            }
            $results[$answer] = $answer_result;
        }
    }else{
        //if test hasn't any answer selected than all answers are wrong 
        $questions = Question::where('test_id', $test_id)->where('deleted',0)->get();

        foreach($questions as $question){
            $answers = Answer::where('question_id', $question->id)->where('deleted',0)->get();
            foreach($answers as $answer){
                $results[] = 0;  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to compare all correct answers with all replied answers. you can count correct answers and "correct replied" answers and see if there is the same number